My ERC20 test is not passing
I got this error when I was try to test my codes.
Here is the link to the github repo: https://github.com/EddiePumpin/hardhat-ERC20
7 passing (3s)
  3 failing

  1) MegaEth Unit Test
       transfers
         Should be able to transfer tokens successfully to an address:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseEther')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\ourToken-unit.test.js:50:45)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

  2) MegaEth Unit Test
       transfers
         emits an transfer event, when an transfer occurs:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC20InsufficientBalance("0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", 50000000, 10000000000000000000)'
    at MegaEth._update (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:195)
    at MegaEth._transfer (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:178)
    at MegaEth.transfer (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:111)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:431:41)
    at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:125:18)
    at send (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:313:20)
    at Proxy.transfer (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:352:16)
    at waitForPendingTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-chai-matchers\src\internal\emit.ts:28:17)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\ourToken-unit.test.js:55:11)


  3) MegaEth Unit Test
       allowances
         Should approve other address to spend token:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseEther')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\ourToken-unit.test.js:67:46)


Created this PR, fixing the errors, you can merge it.
Explanation 
The parseEther error can be solved using ethers.parseEther instead of ethers.utils.parseEther.
The balance issue can be solved by increasing the INITIAL_SUPPLY variable, which is only 50000000 which means 0.00000000005 MegaETH token, considering 18 decimals. And you are trying to send much larger amounts in the test file.
Simply putting this line can solve the issue:
const INITIAL_SUPPLY = ethers.parseEther("50000000");
EDIT: Explanation about decimals.
The solidity language doesn't support floating point. Which means you can't work with numbers like 1.2, 3.1 etc. This is a limitation while working with Tokenomics, as we wan't our tokens to be fractional.
That's why ERC20 has defined Decimals.
If the decimal is 18 (generally it is 18). That means 1 token = 1 * 10 ** 18 = 1000000000000000000 units.
Similar to 1 ETH = 1 * 10 ** 18 wei
So when you passed 50000000 as the INITIAL_SUPPLY, it meant 0.00000000005 tokens. You need to consider the addition and truncation of decimals outside of the contract.
But in the test, you were trying to send ethers.parseEther("0.01") which gives the value of 10000000000000000000.
Which is greater than the actual balance.

It has been fixed but I still don't understand the explanation clearly. I understood the removal of utils from the test file but I don't understand the initial supply part.

added to the answer

Thanks for the explanation
